# Using PHP how can I apply HTMLentities() to a backreference in a preg_replace() call?

Tags: php, regex

At the minute I have:

```
$Text = preg_replace("/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/s", "<mytag>\\1</mytag>", $Text);
```

How can I escape the backreference using `htmlentities()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Text = "foo [code]bla<br>bla[/code] foo";

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/s', 'wrap_code', $Text);

function wrap_code($matches) { 
  return '<mytag>'.htmlspecialchars($matches[1]).'</mytag>';
}
```

As seen in the [`preg_replace_callback()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), you can also create the callback function inline, via `create_function()` or as of PHP 5.3.0 even use an [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

---

The generic approach however would be along the lines of this:

```
$Text = "foo [code]bla<br>bla[/code] foo";

$re_bbcode = '/\[(code|b|whatever)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/s';
echo preg_replace_callback($re_bbcode, 'wrap_code', $Text);

function wrap_code($matches) { 
  switch ($matches[1]) {
    case 'code': $tag = 'mytag'; break;
    case 'b'   : $tag = 'b';     break;
    default    : $tag = ''; 
  }
  if ($tag != '')
    return "<$tag>".htmlspecialchars($matches[2])."</$tag>";
  else
    return htmlspecialchars($matches[0]);
}
```

Also I guess (I have not measured) that this regex could be a bit faster, because the reluctant quantifier would not be invoked more often than necessary:

```
\[(code|b|whatever)\]([^\[]+|.*?)\[\/\1\]
```

Comment: Very interesting, i have now implemented it as an anonymous function. Thanks.